# How do I install Regnum Online?

Tags: installation, games

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter) so please bear with me. I just installed Ubuntu a day or so ago and went looking for an MMO for it. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit and I downloaded Regnum Online from [this page](http://www.regnumonlinegame.com/index.php?l=1&sec=6).

Fast forward to me who just finished downloading the 700mb or so file, when I double clicked on it, it said:

```
Could not display "/home/myname/Downloads/ROInstall_32".

There is no application installed for executable files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
                                           [ NO ] [ YES ]
```

Clicking **Yes**, it scanned for a few moments then came up with **PyPar2** so I installed it. After installing **PyPar2**, I ran it again but I had the feeling I was being whisked further and further away from my goal which is simply to install the game onto my system.

PyPar2 was talking about protection and whatnot so I decided to just quit it and post here and ask for help.

For clarification, yes, I downloaded the Linux version and the download link looked like this.
[image]

Comment: Did you download the Linux version?

Comment: FYI: my installation of regnum did not ask for pypar2. edit: Oh and it looks like pypar2 is used to check integrity of the download ;)

Comment: So how did you install it then @Rinzwind?

Comment: Yes @ObsessiveFOSS. See my screenshot above.

Comment: @ShedoSurashu I found an easier method ;) alsius FTW :+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a permissions issue. Right-click the file, and go to properties.

Go to the permissions tab, and check the checkbox to allow executing this file as a program. Click Close. Try to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that there is a PPA (`ppa:surakin/regnumonline`) for regnum?

https://launchpad.net/~surakin/+archive/regnumonline

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/surakin/regnumonline/ubuntu oneiric main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/surakin/regnumonline/ubuntu oneiric main
```

> Signing key: 1024R/A75CE7F5
>
> Fingerprint: 8CD7852C37DF10A5924342E328BC0D06A75CE7F5

It is 3 weeks behind so the auto-updater might take a bit longer to update to the current release. This way you can use USC to install it.

([Source](http://www.regnumonline.com.ar/forum/showthread.php?t=90581))

---

More info:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal.
2. Use `cd` command to locate the directory where ROinstall is:
3. `chmod 700 ROinstall_32` to make it executable.
4. `./ROinstall` to run it.